# How to implement grid-based movement in SFML?

Tags: c++, c++14, sfml

I can't get good 32x32 grid-based movement in SFML and need some help figuring out how to make it work. This is what I got so far:

```
void player::updateMovement()
{
if(walkFinish) {
    pixelWalked = 0;
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
        direction = 1; // direction set to up

        EndYPos = GetPosition().y - 32; // The position the character is moving towards.

        walkFinish = false;
    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) && canMoveRight) {
        direction = 2; // Right

        EndXPos = GetPosition().x + 32;

        walkFinish = false;
    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
        direction = 3; // Down

        EndYPos = GetPosition().y + 32;

        walkFinish = false;
    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
        direction = 4; // Left

        EndXPos = GetPosition().x - 32;

        walkFinish = false;
    }
} else if(!walkFinish && direction > 0 && direction < 5) { // if walk is not finished, move character.
    if(direction == 1 && !(EndYPos == GetPosition().y)){ // Up
        rect.move(0, -movementSpeed);

    } else if(direction == 2 && !(EndXPos == GetPosition().x) && canMoveRight) { // Right
        rect.move(movementSpeed, 0);

    } else if(direction == 3 && !(EndYPos == GetPosition().y)) { // Down
        rect.move(0, movementSpeed);

    } else if(direction == 4 && !(EndXPos == GetPosition().x)) { // Left
        rect.move(-movementSpeed, 0);
    }
}

if( ((EndXPos == GetPosition().x) && (EndYPos == GetPosition().y)) && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) && !(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) ) {
    walkFinish = true; // if character has reached endpos in both axis, walkFinish becomes true
} else if( ((EndXPos == GetPosition().x) && (EndYPos == GetPosition().y))) { // This gets rid of a 1 frame character pause and makes the movement smoother
    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
        direction = 1; // direction set to up
        EndYPos = GetPosition().y - 32; // Same deal as the first if statement of this function.
    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right) && canMoveRight) {
        direction = 2;
        EndXPos = GetPosition().x + 32;

    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
        direction = 3;
        EndYPos = GetPosition().y + 32;

    } else if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
        direction = 4;
        EndXPos = GetPosition().x - 32;

    }

}
}
```

and my collision check:

```
counter = 0;
for(iterWall = wallArray.begin(); iterWall != wallArray.end(); iterWall++) {
    if(objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x == (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x + 64)) {
        objectPlayer.canMoveLeft = false;
    } else if(objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x == (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x - 64)) {
        objectPlayer.canMoveRight = false;
    } else if(objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y == (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y - 64)) {
        objectPlayer.canMoveDown = false;
    } else if(objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y == (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y + 64)) {
        objectPlayer.canMoveUp = false;
    } else {
        objectPlayer.canMoveUp = true;
        objectPlayer.canMoveRight = true;
        objectPlayer.canMoveDown = true;
        objectPlayer.canMoveLeft = true;
    }

    counter++;
}
```

The problem with this code is the collision part because the character, when it collides with a wall, has a risk of getting stuck. Collision even happens above the wall and my character cant move there because of it. I have no idea how to implement grid-based movement and collision, anyone got a sample code, a blog-post, a tutorial or some hints?

Edit:
The collision part happens before the updateMovement function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out:

```
counter = 0;
    for(iterWall = wallArray.begin(); iterWall != wallArray.end(); iterWall++) {
        if(!leftCheck){
            if( ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x + 64) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x ) && ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y ) ) {
                objectPlayer.canMoveLeft = false; // if character is standing directly to the right of player AND(wall and player is at the same height), player cant move left.
                leftCheck = true;
            } else {
                objectPlayer.canMoveLeft = true;
            }
        }

        if(!rightCheck) {
            if( ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x + - 64) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x ) && ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y ) ) {
                objectPlayer.canMoveRight = false;
                rightCheck = true;
            } else {
                objectPlayer.canMoveRight = true;
            }
        }

        if(!downCheck) {
            if( ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y + 64) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y ) && ( wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x ) ) {
                objectPlayer.canMoveUp = false;
                downCheck = true;
            } else {
                objectPlayer.canMoveUp = true;
            }
        }

        if(!upCheck) {
            if( ( (wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().y - 64) == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().y ) && ( wallArray[counter].rect.getPosition().x == objectPlayer.rect.getPosition().x ) ) {
                objectPlayer.canMoveDown = false;
                upCheck = true;
            } else {
                objectPlayer.canMoveDown = true;
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }
    upCheck = false;
    rightCheck = false;
    downCheck = false;
    leftCheck = false;
```

When I added more walls to my game I realized that the next wall overwrote the previous walls canMoveUp boolean change. To prevent this change I added some checks as seen above in the code. The checks are added once in game startup but not changed anywhere else in the code but here.

and my updateMovement got split in two to prevent a frame pause:

```
void player::updateEndPos() {
    if( (EndXPos == GetPosition().x) && (EndYPos == GetPosition().y) ) {
        if(canMoveUp && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) {
            direction = 1; // direction set to Up

            EndYPos = GetPosition().y - 64; // Sets end-pos so the character knows where to stop.

        } else if(canMoveRight && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
        direction = 2; // direction set to Right

            EndXPos = GetPosition().x + 64;

        } else if(canMoveDown && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) {
            direction = 3; // direction set to Down

        EndYPos = GetPosition().y + 64;

        } else if(canMoveLeft && sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) {
            direction = 4; // direction set to Left

            EndXPos = GetPosition().x - 64;

        }
    }
}
```

as well as:

```
void player::updateMovement() {
    if(EndYPos != GetPosition().y) {
        if(direction == 1) {
            rect.move(0, -movementSpeed); // moves player at "movementSpeed" speed.
        } else if(direction == 3) {
                rect.move(0, movementSpeed);
        } else {
            std::cout << "ERROR IN Y AXIS" << std::endl;
        }
        } else if(EndXPos != GetPosition().x) {
            if(direction == 2) {
                rect.move(movementSpeed, 0);
        } else if(direction == 4) {
            rect.move(-movementSpeed, 0);
        } else {
            std::cout << "ERROR IN X AXIS" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

First I check collision, then I execute updateEndPos() and directly after that I execute updateMovement().

I split up updateEndPos and updateMovement because if I didn't I would've gotten one frame where the updateEndPos() part would not execute and the player would be standing still in that frame. It was very visible but this fixed it and now the character's movement looks smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you do this, but generally you could check the registered move before you apply it (or do the move and undo later if needed) then check if it is colliding with a wall and if it does just ignore the input move. Or you can have a very small margin applied after collision detected so it doesnt collide again if it is not pushed again.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that, my collision check is before my movement so that's not the issue here...